# Should I delete my question or answer my question?

Tags: discussion, answers, unanswered-questions

I am pretty new to this forum and I was wondering what the proper custom would be in my situation. I posted a question a few days ago and last night, after some fiddling with the problem some more I figured out how to get the solution (or what I believe to be it). There are currently no other answers to the question, just some unhelpful comments. I have looked around and it seems different moderators have different opinions.

To me, it seems like a waste to just delete the question because what if someone has a similar question later on? On the other hand, it may look like I am cheating the system somehow (although you don't get points for strictly answering, right?), especially since I didn't check the "answer your own question" box.

Comment: I think the "answer your own question checkbox" merely allows you to type the answer at the same time as you ask the question. At any rate it has been encouraged to answer your own questions, and I would imagine that policy has not changed--for evidence click the link next to the aforementioned checkbox.

Answer (score 33):

If you want to, I think it is good for you to post an answer to your question.  You can even accept your own answer.

> To me, it seems like a waste to just delete the question because what if someone has a similar question later on?

I agree.

> On the other hand, it may look like I am cheating the system somehow

I don't think so.

> (although you don't get points for strictly answering, right?)

Right.  You only get points if someone votes up.  Ordinarily there are points for having your answer accepted, but that doesn't apply if you accept your own answer.

> especially since I didn't check the "answer your own question" box.

I think Karl explained that in a comment; it doesn't apply in this case.

---

> I have looked around and it seems different moderators have different opinions.

In this context, I doubt there is significant opposition.  I have seen some argue against posting questions to which one *already* knew the answer when posting, but even this is still allowed even though some don't like it.  Your case is very different; you asked a question because you wanted to learn the answer, and now you can help the website by answering the question.